# PowerShell - How to check a string to see if it contains another string with wildcard?

Tags: string, powershell, for-loop, pattern-matching, wildcard

I want to go through a list of files and check if each filename match any of the string in a list. This is what I have so far, but it is not finding any match. What am I doing wrong?

```
$files = $("MyApp.Tests.dll","MyApp.Tests.pdb","MyApp.dll")
$excludeTypes = $("*.Tests.dll","*.Tests.pdb")

foreach ($file in $files) 
{
    $containsString = foreach ($type in $ExcludeTypes) { $file | %($_ -match '$type') }

    if($containsString -contains $true)
    {
        Write-Host "$file contains string."
    }
    else
    {
        Write-Host "$file does NOT contains string."
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With wildcards you want to use `-like` operator instead of `-match` because the latter requires a regular expression. Example:

```
$files = @("MyApp.Tests.dll","MyApp.Tests.pdb","MyApp.dll")
$excludeTypes = @("*.Tests.dll","*.Tests.pdb")

foreach ($file in $files) {
    foreach ($type in $excludeTypes) {
        if ($file -like $type) { 
            Write-Host ("Match found: {0} matches {1}" -f $file, $type)
        }
    }
}
```