# Powershell substring check

Tags: powershell

I have this simple script. I just want to match the filename if they contain the substring. However it doesn't work with `-like` or `Contains`. What is the right way to do this?

```
$i = 0
$list1 = @('Gold','Silver')
$list2 = @('W0A-209-193-210_TVIA_Silver_20220520-100001.pdf','W0A-209-195-20_TVIA_Gold_20220520-095934.pdf')
foreach($item in $list2)
    
{
    Write-Host $list1[$i]
    if ($item -like $list1[$i])
    {   
        Write-Host $item + $list1[$i]
        
    }
    $i++
}
```

Expected Output

`W0A-209-193-210_TVIA_Silver_20220520-100001.pdf Silver`

`W0A-209-195-20_TVIA_Gold_20220520-095934.pdf Gold`

Tried this code as well based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896135/powershell-how-to-check-a-string-to-see-if-it-contains-another-string-with-wil) answer but still gives no output

```
$list1 = @('Gold','Silver')
$list2 = @('W0A-209-193-210_TVIA_Silver_20220520-100001.pdf','W0A-209-195-20_TVIA_Gold_20220520-095934.pdf')
foreach($item in $list2)    
{
    foreach($name in $list1)
        {   
            if ($item -like $name)
                {   
                    Write-Host $item + $name
                }
        
        }
    
}
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is how I would solve it**:

```sh
$list1 = @('Gold','Silver')
$list2 = @('W0A-209-193-210_TVIA_Silver_20220520-100001.pdf','W0A-209-195-20_TVIA_Gold_20220520-095934.pdf')

foreach( $filename in $list2 ){
    $list1.Where{ $fileName.Contains( $_ ) }.ForEach{ "$fileName $_" }
}
```

`$list1.Where{ $fileName.Contains( $_ ) }` filters `$list1` based on the given  condition (if the current filename contains the substring). `$_` refers to the current element of `$list1`.

`.ForEach{ "$fileName $_" }` gets called for each filtered element and produces the desired output.

Both `.Where` and `.ForEach` are [intrinsic methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.2#foreach-and-where) that are available for all PowerShell objects, but make the most sense when applied to collections (or in general, types that implement `IEnumerable`).

---

Another approach is to use regular expression matching. Create a RegEx from `$list1` by joining the list items using the RegEx alternation operator `|`:

```sh
$list1 = @('Gold','Silver')
$list1RegEx = $list1 -join '|'

$list2 = @('W0A-209-193-210_TVIA_Silver_20220520-100001.pdf','W0A-209-195-20_TVIA_Gold_20220520-095934.pdf')

foreach( $filename in $list2 ){
    if( $filename -match $list1RegEx ) {
        '{0} {1}' -f $fileName, $matches[0]
    }
}
```

After a successful match, `$matches[0]` contains the first matched substring.

As another variation, I'm using the [format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#format-operator--f) `-f` to produce the desired outcome.

---

**As for what you have tried:**

Your 2nd approach looks most promising. It just has a tiny error in the `-like` condition. The `-like` operator doesn't do a substring search, unless you use wildcards:

```sh
$list1 = @('Gold','Silver')
$list2 = @('W0A-209-193-210_TVIA_Silver_20220520-100001.pdf','W0A-209-195-20_TVIA_Gold_20220520-095934.pdf')

foreach($item in $list2)    
{
    foreach($name in $list1)
    {   
        if ($item -like "*$name*")
        {   
            Write-Host "$item $name"
        }
    }    
}
```